# Error al acceder a valor de Diccionario en Swift 3

Tags: json, xcode, swift3

Tengo el siguiente Json

```
{
   [
          {
            "id": "c200",
            "dia": "Lunes",
            "horario": "07:30/09:20",
            "materia": "Dibujo Tecnico (T)",
            "seccion": "A",
            "profesor" : "Ernesto Arce",
            "aula" : "D1"
          },
          {

            "id": "c383",
            "dia": "Martes",
            "horario": "20:00/21:50",
            "materia": "Sistemas de Telefonia (T)",
            "seccion": "A",
            "profesor" : "-",
            "aula" : "CITEC"

            },
            {

            "id": "c486",
            "dia": "Miercoles",
            "horario": "20:00/21:50",
            "materia": "Materiales 1 (T)",
            "seccion": "A",
            "profesor" : "Gustavo Roman",
            "aula" : "F3"

            }


        ]
}
```

Lo que hago es convertir este Json en un Array de diccionario para así poder acceder a los valores de cada uno. Eso lo hago con la ayuda de mi siguiente código

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire



extension MockData {

    static func index(completion: @escaping ([MockData]) -> Void) {

        Alamofire.request("https://www.dropbox.com/s/fem028u5ok95270/Clases.json?dl=1") .responseJSON { (response) in
            print(response)
            var users = [MockData]()
            if let objects = response.result.value {
                let json = objects as! NSDictionary
                let list = json["Horario"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]

            for object in list! {
                users.append(MockData(dictionary: object))
            }
            }
            completion(users)

        }

    }
}

import UIKit

class MockData: NSObject {

var id : String?
var dia : DiasClases?
var materia : String?
var horario : String?
var seccion : String?
var profesor : String?
//var aula : String?
//var obs : String?
var HorarioArray = [MockData]()


init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]){

    self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String
    self.dia = dictionary["dia"] as? DiasClases
    self.materia = dictionary["materia"] as? String
    self.horario = dictionary["horario"] as? String
    self.seccion = dictionary["seccion"] as? String
    self.profesor = dictionary["profesor"] as? String
    //self.aula = dictionary["aula"] as? String
    //self.obs = dictionary["obs"] as? String

      }


   }


enum DiasClases {
case Lunes
case Martes
case Miercoles
case Jueves
case Viernes
case Sabado

static func AllValues() -> [DiasClases] {
    return [Lunes, Martes, Miercoles, Jueves, Viernes, Sabado]
  }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que al depurar mi programa y verificar que el array este cargado con los datos correctos el item día no contiene nada solo dice DiasClases? y no me guarda el valor del día.
Agradeceria mucho sus ayudas.
Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el JSON, dia no es de tipo DiaClases, es de tipo String. Lo que tienes que haces es sacar primero el día y después convertido al DiaClases que corresponda. En el init sacar el día y después lo guardas como tenga que ser

```
let d = dictionary["dia"] as? String
switch d {
   case "Lunes":
       self.dia = .Lunes
   case "Martes":
       self.dia = .Martes
 .....
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Estaría probando tu código y te aviso qué tal funciona!

Comment: Tu código me funciono de lujo @Spidvmp

Answer (score 0):

Usando el siguiente código:

```
let self.dia = DiasClases(rawValue: dictionary["dia"])!
```

Obtienes el Enumerador que correspoda al valor que le pasas con `dictionary["dia"]`.

Para poder usar éste método en enumeradores con tipos diferentes a `String` debes declarar los `RawValue` de la siguiente forma:

Ejemplo con Int:

Primero definimos cual és el `RawValue` de los enumeradores de la siguiente forma:

```
enum DiasClases: Int {
case Lunes = 1
case Martes = 2
case Miercoles = 3
case Jueves = 4
case Viernes = 5
case Sabado = 6
}
```

Una vez tienes los `RawValue` declarados podemos usar la instrucción para buscar el enumerador del valor que le pasas:

Ejemplo buscando Miércoles:

```
let self.dia = DiasClases(rawValue: 3)!
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta pero yo lo quiero utilizar con enumerados de tipo string